# Tracking tool for entries in EE3

Tags: solspace, ee3, tracking, solspace-tracker

i'm working on a project (EE3) and i need to have a TOP-10 section which is the most read (articles) entries. I had Solspace Tracker on my mind but i saw they will not upgrade it to EE3.

Does anyone know any other add-on or tool or some alternative method to track each entry and then to show the 10 most read entries?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

It has some limitations, but there is the channel entries `track_views` parameter.  More info in [EE3 docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#track-views).